# ansible [Errno 2] A file or directory in the path name does not exist

Tags: ansible

I am executing through an ansible tower the following code:

```
 command:
   chdir={{ __iim_install_location }}/eclipse/tools/
   "su - {{ __was_user }} -c {{ __iim_install_location }}/eclipse/tools/imcl install {{ __product_id }} -acceptLicense -repositories {{ __tmp_dir }}/{{ item.file_name }} -installationDirectory {{ __was_install_location}} -log {{ __log_file }}"
 register:      cout
 with_items:    "{{ __was_this_files }}"
 changed_when:  cout.stdout is defined and ( cout.stdout.find( __version_check ) != -1)
```

I receive the following error. I validate and all the paths exist in the remote host.

```
{
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "check_sum": "866C82D13C24189E880C70AF7AE20143851330AD1C090E0DCF687B612BBC8513",
        "file_name": "8.5.5.16-ws-was-ifph42899.zip"
    },
    "cmd": "'su - was -c /opt/IBM/was/InstallationManager/eclipse/tools/imcl install 8.5.5.16-WS-WAS-IFPH42899_8.5.5016.20211218_1245 -acceptLicense -repositories /mnt/software/IBM/WAS/8.5.5.16-ws-was-ifph42899.zip -installationDirectory /opt/IBM/was5/WebSphere/AppServer -log /opt/IBM/was/logs/was_nd_fix_install.20211223102239.log'",
    "_ansible_item_label": {
        "check_sum": "866C82D13C24189E880C70AF7AE20143851330AD1C090E0DCF687B612BBC8513",
        "file_name": "8.5.5.16-ws-was-ifph42899.zip"
    },
    "rc": 2,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "chdir": "/opt/IBM/was/InstallationManager/eclipse/tools/",
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "_raw_params": "\"su - was -c /opt/IBM/was/InstallationManager/eclipse/tools/imcl install 8.5.5.16-WS-WAS-IFPH42899_8.5.5016.20211218_1245 -acceptLicense -repositories /mnt/software/IBM/WAS/8.5.5.16-ws-was-ifph42899.zip -installationDirectory /opt/IBM/was5/WebSphere/AppServer -log /opt/IBM/was/logs/was_nd_fix_install.20211223102239.log\"",
            "removes": null,
            "argv": null,
            "warn": true,
            "_uses_shell": false,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "stdin": null
        }
    },
    "msg": "[Errno 2] A file or directory in the path name does not exist.: b'su - was -c /opt/IBM/was/InstallationManager/eclipse/tools/imcl install 8.5.5.16-WS-WAS-IFPH42899_8.5.5016.20211218_1245 -acceptLicense -repositories /mnt/software/IBM/WAS/8.5.5.16-ws-was-ifph42899.zip -installationDirectory /opt/IBM/was5/WebSphere/AppServer -log /opt/IBM/was/logs/was_nd_fix_install.20211223102239.log': b'su - was -c /opt/IBM/was/InstallationManager/eclipse/tools/imcl install 8.5.5.16-WS-WAS-IFPH42899_8.5.5016.20211218_1245 -acceptLicense -repositories /mnt/software/IBM/WAS/8.5.5.16-ws-was-ifph42899.zip -installationDirectory /opt/IBM/was5/WebSphere/AppServer -log /opt/IBM/was/logs/was_nd_fix_install.20211223102239.log'"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command passed as parameter `-c` of `su` needs to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's treating your command string as a file.

I believe if you change your play to this:

```
command:
  chdir: {{ __iim_install_location }}/eclipse/tools/
  cmd: "su - {{ __was_user }} -c {{ __iim_install_location }}/eclipse/tools/imcl install {{ __product_id }} -acceptLicense -repositories {{ __tmp_dir }}/{{ item.file_name }} -installationDirectory {{ __was_install_location}} -log {{ __log_file }}"
register:      cout
with_items:    "{{ __was_this_files }}"
changed_when:  cout.stdout is defined and ( cout.stdout.find( __version_check ) != -1)
```

Specifically prefixing the command with `cmd:` , it should work?

Comment: Something is wrong with that sintaxe. Now I have the following: {
    "reason": "We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each: JSON: No JSON object could be decoded\n\nSyntax Error while loading YAML.\n  mapping values are not allowed in this context\n\nThe error appears to be in .../project/roles/was-install-ifix/tasks/install_ifix.yml': line 5, column 8, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n    chdir={{ __iim_install_location }}/eclipse/tools/\n

Comment: cmd: \"su - {{ __was_user }} -c {{ __iim_install_location }}/eclipse/tools/imcl install {{ __product_id }} -acceptLicense -repositories {{ __tmp_dir }}/{{ item.file_name }} -installationDirectory {{ __was_install_location}} -log {{ __log_file }} We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"
}

Comment: Ah, wrap the argument to  `chdir:` in double quotes. But not escaped ones.

Answer (score 0):

Following all the replies and recommendations I ended up with the following code working:

```
- name:          Update IBM WAS Software
  command:
    cmd: "su - {{ __was_user }} -c '{{ __iim_install_location }}/eclipse/tools/imcl install {{ __product_id }} -acceptLicense -repositories {{ __tmp_dir }}/{{ item.file_name }} -installationDirectory {{ __was_install_location}} -log {{ __log_file }}'"
  args: 
    chdir: "{{ __iim_install_location }}/eclipse/tools/"
  register:      cout
  with_items:    "{{ __was_this_files }}"
  changed_when:  cout.stdout is defined and ( cout.stdout.find( __version_check ) != -1)
´´´
```